# How do I convert a DWG floor plan to 3D for use in Unity or PlayCanvas

Tags: unity, 3d, 3d-modeling

I wish to take DWG floor plans and make 3D models of them which I can then use in Unity or PlayCanvas.

[PlayCanvas accepts FBX 3D models](http://developer.playcanvas.com/en/user-manual/assets/models/building/) from tools such as Blender, Sketchup, 3DSMax, Maya, etc.

There are a lot of YouTube videos about creating 3D models from DWG in Sketchup but it seems quite manual work. Is there anything better or more automated?

Would it be better to use something like Blender, 3DSMax, Maya to create the 3D model?

How about AutoCAD - would this be better?

Is there are tool that is tailored for designing 3D floor plans that can export a model? I found [Autodesk Homestyler](http://www.homestyler.com/floorplan/) which makes it easy to create floor plans, and see them in 3D, but only exports DWG.

---

The goal is to use these real life floor plans in a game engine because I want to simulate audio sources in the environment.